# When using a flutter package for drawing board. I want to achieve this functionality make canvas static

Tags: ios, flutter, drawing, android-canvas

When using a flutter package for drawing board. I want to achieve  this functionality make canvas static. here is the package link.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_drawing_board/

Tried to pass the argument of panDisabled and set this parameter to false but that didn't helped.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.